# Melting post-1982 minted U.S. pennies and aluminum: Why does the slag turn blue?

Tags: physical-chemistry, melting-point

After melting aluminum inside of an iron crucible, I tossed in a handful of U.S. pennies that were minted post-1982. [The slag began to burn a brilliant blue.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxsa55fyj43mqz7/Blueburn.mov?dl=0) What caused this?

Comment: Quite possibly copper, but may depend on what country your pennies are from......

Comment: In USA. Was thinking it had something to do with the copper.

Comment: After 1982, U.S. pennies have been minted as copper-plated zinc - see [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_(United_States_coin)#Composition) for information. Apparently 2.5% copper.

Answer (score 3):

[Zinc burns in air forming zinc oxide with a bright blue flame.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSvBV8Su5j8) The bit of copper in US cents will add a greenish color to the flame.

N.B. [Fumes of burning zinc and some other metals are toxic.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_fume_fever) Avoid contact or inhaling the smoke.